# Fetch All fields from a people group field using Caml Query

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query, person-or-group

I have a SharePoint list which contains a people or group field where I want to fetch the Id which is stored internally and name is displayed.

Can anyone tell me how to fetch all the values from person or group field using a CAML query?

It would be a great help.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: do you have people -group internal name ?

Comment: Does your person or group field allows multiple selections? What do you want to fetch exactly? All the users/groups selected in person or group field or something else??

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the Values in person or group field you can use CAML as given below:

```
<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="PersonFieldName"/></ViewFields></View>
```

To Query/Filter for particular user on person or group field you can use anyone of below solutions:

```
<Where>
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="PersonFieldName"/>
    <Value Type="User">User Display Name</Value>
  </Eq>
</Where>
```

Or

```
<Where>
   <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="PersonFieldName" />
      <Value Type="Integer">UserID</Value>
   </Eq>
</Where>
```

Or

```
<Where>
   <Eq>
     <FieldRef Name="PersonFieldName" LookupId="TRUE"/>
     <Value Type="int">UserID</Value>
   </eq>
 </Where>
```

You can also use `<UserID/>` to get the Id which contains:

> Contains the unique ID number of the currently authenticated user of a site, as defined in the UserInfo table of the content database.

Example:

```
<Where>
   <Eq>
      <FieldRef Name="PersonFieldName" />
      <Value Type="Integer">
         <UserID />
      </Value>
   </Eq>
</Where>
```

**References**:

1. [ViewFields element (List)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/viewfields-element-list).
2. [Query schema](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/query-schema).
3. [UserID element (Query)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/userid-element-query).

Comment: Have you tried using this solution?

Comment: Actually what I want is, I am fetching all the data from shrepoint ,now that data has one column called user which is of type people group and it displays name , so when i fetch that data using a SOAP call I get just the name not the other details like email, id etc. so is there any way that those details get fetched instead of name

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are using CAML? you can get those details very easily using REST

Comment: I am bound to use SOAP, not caml

Comment: so using that soap call, I want to get that result

Comment: So you cannot use SharePoint REST?

Comment: No, there are some set standards of organization